# How to configure Nuxt 2.8 to generate ES5-compatible code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js

By default Nuxt generates (by 'nuxt generate') code, which is incompatible with the ES5-standard.

How can I correct it?

What **exactly** needs to be written in nuxt.config.js so that everything is correct? I know that these are some presets for Babel, but I don't know which ones

Thank you!

upd.: Nuxt generated code with 'const' instead 'var' - it is NOT 'ES5 compatible code', isn't it?

Comment: by default nuxt generate code that is working even in ie9

Comment: but do not working in Android 5.1 WebView :(

Comment: it should work.  If it dont its somehting other e.g. third party dependency you are using have that const

Comment: I use Quasar as Nuxt-plugin - maybe that is?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the browser target you can use the following:

```js
build: {
  babel: {
    presets: [
      [
        require.resolve("@nuxt/babel-preset-app"),
        {
          browsers: ["IE 11", "last 2 version"]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

For what you can use in the `browsers` property, please refer to [browserslist documentation](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand, what can I write to get a code without 'const' ('var' instead). Android 5.1 WebView do not run that, becouse 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.' -- I need to get ES5-compatible code - how can I do it?

Comment: Maybe try `safari 5`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Quasar.js connected as Nuxt-plugin (Node-CLI module).

This resolve it:

in nuxt.config.js:

```
build: {
    transpile: [
      'quasar',
    ],
}
```